# The Site cannot be reached - Docker - Gunicorn

Tags: docker, web-server, linux-networking, redhat, gunicorn

I have have a Docker container running on Linux Machine. When I tried to access it on Browser it says

```
This site can’t be reached 10.xxx.xx.xx took too long to respond.
Try: 

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
```

This this is my entrypoint.sh file. This file is being used by Docker

```
exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT:-8000} --timeout 300 -w 4 -t 4 wtools2.wsgi:application
```

Also If I run **netstat -tuln** command it shows following

Active Internet connections (only servers)

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xx:8000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xx:5000        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I also asked our Network Engineer to check any communication blocks He says

> 'the communication flow is allowed from network side, no restriction for whole subnet'

Currently I am using RHEL Server

**Docker Compose File**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /code/entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - ./wtools2:/code/wtools2
    ports:
      - "${PORT:-8000}:8000"
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=wtools2.settings_production
      - PYTHONPATH=/code/
      - DJANGO_ENV=production
```

Comment: Could you provide a docker-compose.yaml file? Did you try a new network for the container instead of the default one?

Comment: Hi @OmidEstaji, I have added my docker-compose.yaml file